Send `kill -SIGUSR1` to daemon process
Suppose you have a daemon process owned by user foo and group foo and can be initiated via sudo systemctl start foo.service.
This daemon spends most of its time waiting on a sub process sleep, but can be interrupted by SIGUS1 to perform some tasks via a trap.
When the signal is received it will read from a named pipe, perform some tasks and return stdout and stderr to another named pipe.
Suppose there is a user bar who is a part of the foo group.
This user has access to shell script called talk_foo which attempts to send a signal, and then read from the daemon's output named pipe to echo back to the user.
Is it possible for user bar to send kill -SIGUSR1 <DAEMON PID>? So far I have been unsuccessful (unless using sudo), as the operation is not permitted. I suppose this is because the use bar does not own the daemon process nor are they a part of the same process group.
Is there a way to communicate with the foo daemon in this setup, or should I rethink things?

Is there a way to communicate with the foo daemon Yes, but not by using kill! You could use Unix sockets, pipes or even some rendez-vous file, then play with permisisions (prw--w----, user-group-others). Btw, waiting for input in a simple named fifo could replace the use of some sleep infinity.

Signals are a common IPC, but by no means the only option. Beware the X/Y Problem; address the problem, not your approach to the problem. You could do something as simple as dropping a "flag file" as a semaphore, though a named pipe is certainly more flexible.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub, this was what I was considering as an alternative. I wasn't sure if having a while read -u <named pipe in> -r line expression would cause a lot of CPU usage. The main motivation to using the kill was that the daemon only responded when it needed.

Blocking on a pipe causes no CPU usage.

@JustinLandis Not read -u, just read -r varname </path/to/fifo.

I know you mentioned sudo, but maybe you don't know that you can setup sudo for one specific command which the user can run as specified user without password. So you make a script (which a user can't modify ofcourse) and the user can call the script with sudo.

I am now finding that it would be useful to still send a single to inturrpt the daemon, in the case that the user does a SIGINT. In this case, is the only way to send a signal through sudo as @gabor.zed has said?

Another way I handle this type of other user situations is inotifywait. With this gem you can use a simple text file to send commands to your script. In this case maybe it is more complicated, because your script is waiting elsewhere so you probably need a separate script which uses the inotifywait and sends tell kill signal to your main script.

Thank you to everyone who has commented information, it has been very helpful.
I ultimately dropped my implementation of using a sleep cycle and interrupting with a kill -SIGUSR1 signal and the motivation behind that was to keep the cpu usage within a while true loop low.
Thanks to @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub and @Barmar, Reading from the named pipe to block the process until that pipe is written to by the user remedies the CPU usage problem as well as the communication problem.
Below is my end result, mostly for future reference. Cheers!
In daemon example
FIFO=my_pipe
# allow group access to write to input
mkfifo 0620 $FIFO.in
# allow group access to read from output
mkfifo 0640 $FIFO.out

some_custom_cmd() {
  #do whatever here
  echo "Responding... " $@
}

read_and_respond() {
  exec <3$FIFO.in  # open input pipe
  # attempt to read from it
  # blocking process here until user writes to
  # $FIFO.in
  read -u 3 -r user_cmd 
  # once process continues and we capture user input
  # close input and open ouptut pipe
  exec 3<&- 4>$FIFO.out 
  # perform some task, writing to pipe
  # which blocks process until user reads from
  # $FIFO.out
  some_custom_cmd $user_cmd >&4 2>&4
  # close fd 4 when done
  exec 4>&-
 }

while true
do
  # blocking process
  read_and_respond
done

The above daemon process would run in the background.
on the user script side...
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# assuming everything is in the same
# directory... probably best to put in
# some /run/<group>/ directory
FIFO=my_pipe
talk_to_daemon() {
  #open file descriptor
  exec 3>$FIFO.in
  echo $@ >&3 # send arguments to daemon, releases blocking
  exec 3>&- 4<$FIFO.out  #close fd 3, open fd 4 for reading
  #blocks process until daemon responds by writing to
  # $FIFO.out
  # here we are just verbatim printing to the user
  cat <&4 
  exec 4<&- # closes fd 4 when done

}

talk_to_daemon $@

@gabor.zed mentioned configuring sudoers. This would allow for the original setup of using a trap, but I think the above approach is much cleaner.
